# Remove numbered keys from object recursively

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following JSON.

```
var a = {
  "0": "123",
  "1": 'gio',
  "again": "blabla",
  "ah" : "fff",
  "ss" : {
    "0": "444",
    "1": "555",
    "final": "letssee"
  }
}
```

I want to get the following one

```
var a = {
  "again": "blabla",
  "ah" : "fff",
  "ss" : {
    "final": "letssee"
  }
}
```

The idea is that we recursively go through the whole object and remove all the keys that are numbers. Object could go deeper and deeper, so that's why we need recursion.

I tried to come up with a code, but somehow my solution is huge, and very ugly.

I'd appreciate a ES6 way(clean and easy)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const isObj = (x) => x !== null && typeof x === "object" && !Array.isArray(x);

const removeNumericKeys = (o) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).flatMap(([k, v]) =>
      isNaN(Number(k)) ? [[k, isObj(v) ? removeNumericKeys(v) : v]] : []
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

basically you can loop using `for ... in` using recursion and check for the keys of the object using `parseInt` with `isNaN` to check if it is numeric or not.

this is a destructive way to achive it, if you look, it will change the principal object.

```js
let obj = {
  "0": "123",
  "1": 'gio',
  "again": "blabla",
  "ah": "fff",
  "ss": {
    "0": "444",
    "1": "555",
    "final": "letssee"
  }
}

function deleteRecursive(obj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    const parsedKey = parseInt(k);
    // if it is NOT NAN it means it is numeric, so we delete it
    if (!isNaN(parsedKey)) {
      delete obj[k];
    } else if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
      deleteRecursive(obj[k]);
    }
  }
}

deleteRecursive(obj);

console.log(obj)
```

this is another way to do it if you want to keep the old object and assign it to a new one.

```js
let obj = {
  "0": "123",
  "1": 'gio',
  "again": "blabla",
  "ah": "fff",
  "ss": {
    "0": "444",
    "1": "555",
    "final": "letssee"
  }
}

let newObj = {}

function deleteRecursive(obj, newObj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    const parsedKey = parseInt(k);
    // if it is NOT NAN it means it is numeric, so we dont add it
    if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
      newObj[k] = {}
      deleteRecursive(obj[k], newObj[k]);
    } else if (isNaN(parsedKey)) {
      newObj[k] = obj[k]
    }
  }
}

deleteRecursive(obj, newObj);

console.log(newObj)
```